# how to serilaze and unserialize an array in php

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'type'     => 'airport ',
    'airport'  => 'Delhi Indra Gandhi',
    'address'  => '',
    'city'     => '',
    'postcode' => ''
);
```

I serialized it and saved it wp database.

```
  $wpdb->insert( 'table_name', serialize($arr), '%s' );
```

When I am selecting this data in front end it giving me string like this

```
    a:5:{s:4:\"type\";s:7:\"airport\";s:7:\"airport\";s:18:\"Delhi Indra 
    Gandhi\";s:7:\"address\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"city\";s:0:\"\";s:8:\"postcode\";s:0:\"\";}
```

When I am unserializing it , it gives nothing means an empty string.
Kindly help me.

Comment: Works fine here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/xpvB2b

Comment: The slashes in front of your quotes are causing the error.

Answer (score -1):

When you unserialize use urldecode and unserialize example:

```
$str = serialize($arr);
$strenc = urlencode($str);
```

Unserialize:

```
$array = unserialize(urldecode($strenc));
```